# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

Tags: python, java, pip, pyinstaller, pyenv

I am using python 3.11.5 and pytinstaller to convert my python scripts to exe but i have this error Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in *run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*init**.py", line 45, in 
import pkg_resources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'   how i can solve it?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in *run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*init**.py", line 45, in 
import pkg_resources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'